# SQL find name doubles and sum values

Tags: sql, duplicates

I have one table records with the columns:

```
|rec.id|rec.name|user.name|hours|
```

and the values respectively:

```
|1     |google  |Admin    | 12  |
|2     |yahoo   |Admin    | 1   |
|3     |bing    |Manager  | 4   |
```

What i want to do is take all of the records with the same user.id and sum there hours together in SQL. Perhaps its the early mornign but i cant seem to figure out a way of doing this. I thought about using sql to find the duplicates but thats only going to return a number and not what i want to do with them. This sounds like a really simple thing so sorry in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select   user_name,
         sum(hours)
from     your_table
group by user_name;
```

Answer (score 2):

You would group on the user name and use the `sum` aggregate on the hours:

```
select [user.name], sum(hours) as hours
from TheTable
group by [user.name]
```